# Decimal field in Django Admin Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model which includes a field:

```
TAX_CHOICES = (
    (10.5, '10.5%'),
    (17.5, '17.5%'),
    (30, '30%'),
    (33, '33%'),
)

taxBracket = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, choices=TAX_CHOICES, default=10.5)
```

I have existing Django forms which work in my application to allow users to enter their tax bracket successfully. However, I need to manually add some user information via the Django Admin interface but am getting an error as follows when I select 10.5 or 17.5 values:

```
Value Decimal('10.5') is not a valid choice
```

I understand from reading the Django docs that the Admin form treats DecimalField types as a 'text' input, but am not sure whether I should be looking at the Model definition or a customisation of the Admin form. I do not currently have an admin.py defined in this project for Admin site customisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have defined the field options as floats. The float `10.5` does not equal the decimal `Decimal("10.5")`.

Either define the choices as strings or as decimals:

```
TAX_CHOICES = (
    (Decimal("10.5"), '10.5%'),
    (Decimal("17.5"), '17.5%'),
    (Decimal("30"), '30%'),
    (Decimal("33"), '33%'),
)
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. I wasn't aware of the difference between Decimal and Float in Python. [This Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) explains the difference clearly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: It's worth noting that Django choices are also sensitive to how you instantiate the Decimal. So in my case Decimal('20.00') worked but Decimal('20') and Decimal(20) did not.